# Entity Framework mapping with a shared entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I have an object called `Trip`. `Trip` has many `Destinations`. `Destinations` has many `Photos` (optional). However, a `Trip` can also have a `Photo` from one of the `Destinations`.

A `Photo` can be used as a cover photo for a trip as well as the cover photo for a destination, so rather than make the user upload the same photo twice, I have two properties on `Photo`: IsTripCoverPhoto and IsDestinationCoverPhoto.

So, `Photo` looks something like this:

```
public partial class Photo : Entity
{
    public Photo()
    {
        Id = GuidComb.GenerateComb();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Destination Destination { get; set; }
    public virtual Trip Trip { get; set; }
    public bool IsTripCoverPhoto { get; set; }
    public bool IsDestinationCoverPhoto { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `Trip` mapping:

```
public class TripMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Domain.DomainModel.Entities.TripModels.Trip>
{

    public TripMapping()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired();
        HasOptional(t => t.User).WithMany(t => t.Trips).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasRequired(x => x.Settings);
        HasMany(x => x.Destinations).WithRequired(x => x.Trip).Map(x => x.MapKey("Trip_Id")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        // HasOptional(x => x.Photo).WithRequired(x=>x.Trip).Map(x=>x.MapKey("Trip_Id")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasOptional(t => t.Photo).WithRequired(x => x.Trip).Map(m => m.MapKey("Trip_Id")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


}
```

This is my `Destination` mapping:

```
public DestinationMapping()
 {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired();
        HasMany(x => x.Activities).WithRequired(x => x.Destination);
        HasMany(x => x.Photos).WithRequired(x => x.Destination).Map(x => x.MapKey("Destination_Id")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Photo upload works fine and if I add to `TripMapping`:

```
HasOptional(x => x.Photo).WithOptionalPrincipal(x=>x.Trip);
```

I get the upload records being added to the database, but only the first photo has a `Trip_Id`... all subsequent records are inserted with NO `Trip_Id`. I am definitely adding the both the destination and trip to the photo and I've tracked it all the way to when it adds it and there are no problems that I can tell. I really think it has something to do with my mapping, but I just do not know what it is!

I've tried every-which-way to map, but cannot for the life of me get my site to insert a photo into the DB with both a `Trip_Id` and a `Destination_Id`...

I tried adding mapping to the photo:

```
public PhotoMapping()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired();

        HasRequired(x=>x.Trip).WithOptional(x=>x.Photo).Map(x=>x.MapKey("Trip_Id")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasRequired(x => x.Destination).WithMany(x=>x.Photos).Map(x => x.MapKey("Destination_Id")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

How can I perform this mapping such that my uploaded photos have both a trip and a destination?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I added to `TripMapping`:

```
  HasOptional(x => x.Photo).WithMany().Map(x => x.MapKey("Trip_Id"));
```

No idea why the above works, yet below does not...

```
 HasOptional(t => t.Photo).WithRequired(x => x.Trip).Map(m => m.MapKey("Trip_Id")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```